# Any limitation of grep command?

Tags: grep

Is there any limitation of grep command?

I have a 548KB syslog file, I use the grep command to filter it.

I got 2583 lines output, the last line show the end of time May 28 05:37:40; But actually, after May 28 05:37:40 there are more lines meet the keyword `ddclient`.

Why?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here are null characters in your syslog file.
You can check for null characters using:

```
xxd -g1 /var/log/syslog | cut -f2-17 -d' ' | grep -n 00
```

so you will get an output similar to this:

```
18944:29 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

then you can `xxd` the whole file again to get further context around the matching line(s) (nr. 18944 in this case):

```
xxd /var/log/syslog | grep -n . | grep '18944:' -C5
```

The output will show the desired line + 5 lines before and after to see further context:

```
18939:00049fa0: 7420 3139 2074 6f20 3437 2e31 3036 2e31  t 19 to 47.106.1
18940:00049fb0: 3636 2e37 2c20 706f 7274 2034 3633 3234  66.7, port 46324
18941:00049fc0: 2028 6572 726e 6f20 3130 3120 2d20 4e65   (errno 101 - Ne
18942:00049fd0: 7477 6f72 6b20 6973 2075 6e72 6561 6368  twork is unreach
18943:00049fe0: 6162 6c65 2920 286e 6574 2e63 3a32 3930  able) (net.c:290
18944:00049ff0: 290a 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  )...............
18945:0004a000: 4d61 7920 3238 2030 363a 3137 3a30 3820  May 28 06:17:08 
18946:0004a010: 7261 7370 6265 7272 7970 6920 7379 7374  raspberrypi syst
18947:0004a020: 656d 642d 6d6f 6475 6c65 732d 6c6f 6164  emd-modules-load
18948:0004a030: 5b31 3137 5d3a 2049 6e73 6572 7465 6420  [117]: Inserted 
18949:0004a040: 6d6f 6475 6c65 2027 6932 635f 6465 7627  module 'i2c_dev
```

Comment: First of all: thanks for your detail replay.

Comment: First of all: thanks for your detail replay. I have try to find with your command. The last line around line 18435. I am not sure which non-printable characters in there. [link]https://imgbox.com/Jz0NBStP

Comment: My approach is not bullet-proof, for example I should omit newlines (0x0a). Would you mind sharing your complete syslog file through some sharing service (like dropbox, Google drive or similar)?

Comment: Yes please.I think this the best way to find root cause.[link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Amm2uJKDz845191fahHPprhXUpoEdajX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: ok, I have requested access from my gmail account.

Comment: I already click "share".

Comment: I edited my answer to match your real file. The problem is just the 0x00 characters, not any other non-printable ones. I realized that earlier, but then over-combined my thoughts. "tr -d '\000'" from the adjacent answer does the job, but my answer tells you where actually is the problem.

Comment: You find the root cause, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your grep command is tripping up somewhere in the file after some invalid characters potentially? The output of "Binary file /var/log/syslog matches" means that at some point grep considered the file binary.

Mind manually looking in the file around May 28 05:37:40? Is there a null terminator in there or some other corruption potentially?

You might take a look at this question for more details on grep and binary files: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19907/what-makes-grep-consider-a-file-to-be-binary

Comment: I try your way to use command: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo cat syslog | tr -d '\000'|grep ddclient. This way show the all things from file with grep command.  Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Command $ sudo cat syslog | tr -d '\000'|grep ddclient. is the workaround for this case, it's really work. The ask ubuntu can't mark all both two be accepted answers. I think need to give the accepted answer for who find the root cause. Many thanks both of you, Cost your time.